# Ansible is connecting to the wrong hosts when using jump host

Tags: ansible

I am managing hosts in two different data centers. I get to the managed hosts via a jump host. There is a dedicated jump host for each data center. My inventory files look something like:

```
$ cat inventory-dc1
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@10.1.1.1"'

[docker]
docker-1 ansible_host=192.168.1.1
docker-2 ansible_host=192.168.1.2

$ cat inventory-dc2
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@10.1.1.2"'

[docker]
docker-1 ansible_host=192.168.1.1
docker-2 ansible_host=192.168.1.2
```

When I run a playbook with `inventory-dc1` everything works as expected.

The problem manifests when I subsequently run a playbook with `inventory-dc2`. Ansible connects to the hosts from `inventory-dc1` instead of `inventory-dc2`. I know that the managed hosts have the same IP addesses but they are accessed via different jump hosts.

Answer (score 2):

Make unique control path for each inventory:

```
[all:vars]
ansible_ssh_common_args='-o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -q ubuntu@10.1.1.1" -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=~/.ansible/cp/dc1-ssh-%C'
```

Note `dc1` prefix for path. Specify `dc2` for the second inventory.

Comment: Good idea! It's working for me but I had to comment out `ssh_args = ...` from `ansible.cfg`. Otherwise it will overwrite the above configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Ansible automatically enables SSH multiplexing. It means the ssh connections made by Ansible look something like this:

```
CP=~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r
ssh -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ControlPath=$CP \
ubuntu@192.168.1.1 /bin/true
```

This will create a socket like `~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.1.1-22-ubuntu` and keep it open for 60 seconds. If you run another ssh connection with the same IP address, port and username within 60 seconds you will get connected to the same host.

The solution that worked for me was to disable SSH multiplexing for Ansible:

```
$ cat ansible.cfg
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no
```

It's not an optimal solution because it slows down Ansible.

Another (suboptimal :-) solution is to manually remove the socket(s):

```
rm ~/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-192.168.1.1-22-ubuntu
```